# xrandr settings make one screen extend beyond the display

Tags: xrandr

I've been mucking around with this for ages now and have hit a wall. I can't find exactly what I'm looking for anywhere through searching either.

My setup is two 4K monitors. The one on the left is the internal laptop monitor that I want to increase the size of by about 10%. The one on the right is a huge 4K that can stay 1x1.

The randr stanza

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --pos 0x0 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 0.9x0.9 --primary --output DP-1-2 --pos 3840x0 --mode 3840x2160
```

gets the screens about the right resolution, but the menu on the bottom drops off the visible area of the screen.

I've tried setting --fbmm 8064x4536 and --fbmm 7640x4320 but they doesn't do it for me either.

I've got to be close, anyone know what the stanza should be?

Comment: X.org is not very good at different scale settings for different screens especially if they are not in doubles or halves. 10% isn't that much. Are you sure it's really needed? It's usually better to adjust these things using window settings, although this is not a feature of GNOME where the design language is "worse is better". You can also try to log off and log in with Wayland and see if that meets your needs better. I'm also assuming that you made a typo in your question as the last bit ends with `--mode 3840x216`

Comment: Thanks @Nmath, indeed 10% isn't much, but its enough it seems.. I have been using wayland, but the problem is that none of the screen sharing apps will work with it, so I'm forced back to X. 

I may have found the answer though. I'm using KDE and restarting plasma pulls the menu back to where it should be, so I may be onto it. :)

I'll report back if that is the fix.

Comment: Ah great! I was actually going to recommend KDE if you weren't able to find settings that work well in GNOME. Let us know.  And consider posting an answer if you find a solution. It could help future visitors if they have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems the missing piece is the restarting of plasma after changing the screen if the menu doesn't appear where it should.

```
 →  kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
```

Still playing with the fbmm settings, but its working pretty well at the moment.